# Написать bash скрипт - самый новый файл из списка

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

Здравствуйте. Только начал изучить баш и никак не могу придумать решение. Необходимо написать shell script, в который я могу передать некоторое количество файлов, и он выдаст мне самый новый по времени. Комманда ls -t | head -1 вернет мне самый новый файл в директории. Как написать скрипт, который можно было бы выполнить из консоли, передав список файлов (например, список из 2,3,4..9 файлов) [Количество файлов заранее неизвестно], и в результате выполнения которого, будет получен один самый новый по времени файл?

Comment: вы можете список файлов передать параметрами той же ls

Comment: спасибо, не додумался сразу сам)) Это сработало. А как можно сделать такое с помощью команды find -cnewer?

Comment: `-cnewer <FILE>` -- это немного не про то.

Answer (score 8):

список всех переданных скрипту оций и параметров доступен в переменной `$@`. при обращении к ней имеет смысл заключать её в кавычки — `"$@"`, для того, чтобы опции/параметры, содержащие пробелы (`'пара метр1' пара\ метр2` и т.п.), не разбивались по этим самым пробелам.

1. можно воспользоваться той же программой *ls* (опция `-t` сортирует по времени последней модификации файла, причём в обратном порядке — первым в списке будет файл, модифицированный самым последним):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ls -t "$@" | head -1
   ```
2. а можно пойти более сложным и длинным путём. например, воспользоваться программой *stat*, которая умеет выводить, к примеру, и время модификации файла (`%Y` в строке формата вывода, задаваемого опцией `-c`):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   stat -c '%Y %n' "$@" | sort | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Находит самый свежий файл и выводит только его имя.

```
ls -t | head -2 | tail -n1 | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f 9
```